# How do I get the user controls to Resize themselves properly?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I feel bad about not getting this. 
But, although I have read several articles on measure pass and arrange pass and written several small programs, I still have a hard time with this.

It makes sense to me that any user control will have a "minimum size" (after which only possible solution would be to shrink it as a whole bitmap wise or add a scroll bar). It will also have a way to use any additional screen real estate given to it.

Ellipses have no minimum size and can collapse to size zero.

So, consider this example

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="20">
        <Ellipse Fill="Blue"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="Green"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="BlueViolet"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

what is the least amount of xaml code needed to add to achieve the following effects:

- Make them force a "minimum size" of uniform 40. And dynamically resize uniformly.
- Make them force a "minimum size" of uniform 40. And dynamically resize non-uniformly (so that the they can stretch really wide, but will never size below 40/40).
- Make them force a minimum height, but stretch to available width.
- Make them stretch uniformly fitting a constant height of the stackpanel.
- Make the stackpanel stretch to fill the dynamic height of its container.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most of those cases you probably want to use a [`UniformGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx) with one column instead of a `StackPanel`. To force sizes use a [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.aspx) which sets the [`MinHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.minheight.aspx) and [`MinWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.minwidth.aspx). If the uniformity is guaranteed to be "one-way" you can just bind the [`Width`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx) to the [`ActualHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx).

Comment: Do you mean one row to match horizontal?

Comment: @BalamBalam: I do not know what you mean... (also i am not quite sure about the OP either, those are a lot of szenarios)

Comment: @BalamBalam: Yes. The 1 row setting is to mimic the horizontal orientation setting of the stackpanel.